# converting prn to lbl format in zebra designer

Tags: zebra-printers

We have a bunch of .prn files. These files dont open in Zebra Designer.

Is there a way to convert .prn to .lbl file so that they open in the designer software?

I tried renaming .prn to .lbl but the designer complains

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I think it is impossible: only a software made by Zebra could do it, because LBL files are binary and PRN are plain text. Unless the source code is open, there is no conventional way to do it, except using reverse engineering.